# ¿Se puede pedir al usuario la suma de dos numeros aleatorios en python?

Tags: python, random

Estoy realizando un juego sencillo en donde se generarán dos números aleatorios usando 'randint' en python, dichos numeros los almaceno en dos variables diferentes (dado1 y dado2) y la suma de los mismos en otra variable (resultado) pero al momento de que el usuario ingresa la respuesta correcta a la suma el programa la marca como incorrecta. ¿Es válido lo que estoy haciendo?

```
#Dados y sumas
import random

print('¿Quien inicia el juego')
start = random.randint(0,1)

if start == 0:
    print("Comienza el jugador 1°")
    lanzaDado1 = input(('\nPresiona 1 para lanzar tu primer dado: '))
    dado1 = random.randint(1,6)

    print('Tu primer número es: ',dado1)

    lanzaDado2 = input(('\nPresiona 1 para lanzar tu segundo dado: '))
    dado2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print('Tu segundo número es: ',dado2)

    resultado = dado2 + dado1

    suma = input(("Introduce la suma de tus números: "))
    if suma == resultado:
        print("Correcto!")
        print(f"\nQuitale la ficha número{resultado} a tu oponente")
    else:
        print("Incorrecto, fin de turno...")

else:
    print("Comienza el jugador 1°")
    lanzaDado1 = input(('\nPresiona 1 para lanzar tu primer dado: '))
    dado1 = random.randint(1,6)

    print('Tu primer número es: ',dado1)

    lanzaDado2 = input(('\nPresiona 1 para lanzar tu segundo dado: '))
    dado2 = random.randint(1,6)
    print('Tu segundo número es: ',dado2)

    resultado = dado2 + dado1

    suma = input(("Introduce la suma de tus números: "))
    if suma == resultado:
        print("Correcto!")
        print(f"\nQuitale la ficha número{resultado} a tu oponente")
    else:
        print("Incorrecto, fin de turno...")
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero de todo el `if Start == 0:` podrías ponerlo como `if not Start`, aunque sinceramente no le veo ninguna utilidad
debido a que salga 0 o 1 el programa acaba en el mismo código; no sé si esperabas otro comportamiento o que según el start
determinase quién comienza el juego.

El problema que tienes es debido a que en Python un `input` siempre devuelve un `String` y entonces no comparas si 3 es igual a 3, sino que comparas si 3 es igual a "3" y por eso ¡siempre te sale incorrecto!

El problema se soluciona pasando tu cadena de caracteres a un número, usando la función `int()` que transforma un string a número entero siempre que sea posible.

Aquí te dejo el código arreglado y con como creo que querías hacer el sistema de turnos.

```
#Dados y sumas
import random

print('¿Quien inicia el juego')
comienza = random.randint(1,2)

print(f"Comienza el jugador {comienza}°")
lanzaDado1 = input(('\nPresiona 1 para lanzar tu primer dado: '))
dado1 = random.randint(1,6)

print('Tu primer número es: ',dado1)

lanzaDado2 = input(('\nPresiona 1 para lanzar tu segundo dado: '))
dado2 = random.randint(1,6)

print('Tu segundo número es: ',dado2)

resultado = dado2 + dado1

suma = int(input(("Introduce la suma de tus números: ")))

if suma == resultado:
    print("Correcto!")
    print(f"\nQuitale la ficha número {resultado} a tu oponente")
else:
    print("Incorrecto, fin de turno...")
```

Comment: Wow. Muchas gracias, soy nuevo en python y a veces se me van algunos detalles. Aprecio mucho la ayuda!